# I get an error after I log out of my facebook api application , session still valid?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So I installed the facebook login feature to my website through the facebook api , it works fine , but after logging out with the facebook log-out button , I get the following error message below ... I've heard it's because my session is still active but I never used the session function in the good , I used the getUser() method instead

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
    [result:protected] => Array
        (
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.
                    [type] => OAuthException
                    [code] => 190
                    [error_subcode] => 467
                )

        )

    [message:protected] => Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /home/content/72/9959172/html/madscore/facebook/facebook-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
    [line:protected] => 1238
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/content/72/9959172/html/madscore/facebook/facebook-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
                    [line] => 870
                    [function] => throwAPIException
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [error] => Array
                                        (
                                            [message] => Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.
                                            [type] => OAuthException
                                            [code] => 190
                                            [error_subcode] => 467
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [function] => _graph
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /me
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/content/72/9959172/html/madscore/facebook/facebook-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
                    [line] => 644
                    [function] => call_user_func_array
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Facebook Object
                                        (
                                            [sharedSessionID:protected] => 
                                            [appId:protected] => 314286708589099
                                            [appSecret:protected] => 8f803e0f9e9da4f2ba9f23ad3bd00ded
                                            [user:protected] => 
                                            [signedRequest:protected] => 
                                            [state:protected] => 
                                            [accessToken:protected] => 
                                            [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
                                            [trustForwarded:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => _graph
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => /me
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/content/72/9959172/html/madscore/authentication.php
                    [line] => 34
                    [function] => api
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /me
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/content/72/9959172/html/madscore/auth_output.php
                    [line] => 2
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /home/content/72/9959172/html/madscore/authentication.php
                        )

                    [function] => include_once
                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The FB api uses SESSIONS internally.

After you logout, check your $_SESSION array, and you'll probably find FB related things there.

When I had a similar problem, I had to manually delete those myself to be able to complete my logouts.

Comment: I didn't initialize a session though

Comment: You don't have to. The FB api does that for you.
After you logout, initialize a session and check out the session array and you'll see the FB vars there.

Comment: could you show me how to initialize that session through the facebook api ??

Comment: You don't initialize it through the api.
To initialize it add a session_start(); before any output on your code (generally in the beginning of if) and then print_r($_SESSION) will show you the session vars. Probably, FB vars will be there.